# PDFJet-Open-source: How to set multiline text inside Cell object

Tags: android

I use PDFJet-Open-Source library to construct a pdf. So, I have couple of questions:

1) How can I place the multiline text inside Cell?

**Problem description:** Currently I faced with problem that I can't place the multiline text inside Cell object. I tried set text like `"text1 \n text2..."` but it does not have any effect. Unfortunatelly, open source version does not have TextColumn and Paragraph classes.

2) What is the CompositeTextLine and how to use it?

**Problem description:** Perhaps I have wrong imagination, but I tried to do the following:

```
...
CompositeTextLine ctl = new CompositTextLine(0,0);
ctl.addComponent(new TextLine(f1,"MyText1"));
ctl.addComponent(new TextLine(f1,"MyText2"));
ctl.addComponent(new TextLine(f1,"MyText3"));
Cell cell = new Cell(f1);
cell.setCompositeTextLine(ctl);
...
```

I expected to see several multiple lines in the Cell but I observed nothing. Moreover, if I add the line `table.wrapAroundCellText()`, I've got **NullPointerException**. If I call `ctl.drawOn(page)`, I just observe: "MyText1 MyText2 MyText3" without line breaking.

**UPDATE:** I discovered the TextBox class, so that, if I write:

```
TextBox textbox = new TextBox(f1);
textbox.setText("First Line \n Second Line");
textbox.drawOn(page);
```

it will construct what I want:

```
First Line
Second Line
```

But still I am interested with the possibility of (1) and description of (2) and some of them variations, like to "How to set TextBox (or image etc.) inside Cell, not only single line?"

And last one, could anyone, please, refer me to the realization of "text justification" algorithm in Java or C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can across the same problem, and I ended up extending Cell, and using [WordUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) from [apache commons lang3](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html):

```
public class MultilineCell extends Cell {

    private final int characterCount;

    public MultilineCell(Font font, String content, int characterCount) {
        super(font, content);
        this.characterCount = characterCount;
    }

    @Override
    public String getText() {
        return WrapUtil.wrap(super.getText(), this.characterCount);
    }

    @Override
    public float getHeight() {
        float height = this.font.getBodyHeight();

        String text = getText();
        if (text != null) {
            String[] wrappedTexts = text.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

            if (wrappedTexts.length > 1) {
                return (height * wrappedTexts.length) + this.top_padding + this.bottom_padding;
            }
        }
        return height + this.top_padding + this.bottom_padding;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paint(Page page, float x, float y, float w, float h) throws Exception {
        page.setPenColor(this.getPenColor());
        page.setPenWidth(this.lineWidth);

        drawBorders(page, x, y, w, h);
        drawText(page, x, y, w);
    }

    private void drawBorders(
            Page page,
            float x,
            float y,
            float cell_w,
            float cell_h) throws Exception {

        if (getBorder(Border.TOP) &&
                getBorder(Border.BOTTOM) &&
                getBorder(Border.LEFT) &&
                getBorder(Border.RIGHT)) {
            page.drawRect(x, y, cell_w, cell_h);
        }
        else {
            if (getBorder(Border.TOP)) {
                page.moveTo(x, y);
                page.lineTo(x + cell_w, y);
                page.strokePath();
            }
            if (getBorder(Border.BOTTOM)) {
                page.moveTo(x, y + cell_h);
                page.lineTo(x + cell_w, y + cell_h);
                page.strokePath();
            }
            if (getBorder(Border.LEFT)) {
                page.moveTo(x, y);
                page.lineTo(x, y + cell_h);
                page.strokePath();
            }
            if (getBorder(Border.RIGHT)) {
                page.moveTo(x + cell_w, y);
                page.lineTo(x + cell_w, y + cell_h);
                page.strokePath();
            }
        }

    }

    private void drawText(
            Page page,
            float x,
            float y,
            float cell_w) throws IOException {

        String wrappedText = WrapUtil.wrap(super.getText(), this.characterCount);
        String[] lines = wrappedText.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

        float x_text = x + this.left_padding;
        float y_text = y + this.font.getAscent() + this.top_padding;

        for (String line : lines) {
            page.drawString(this.font, line, x_text, y_text);
            y_text += this.font.getBodyHeight();
        }
    }
}
```

You can instantiate and add the MultilineCell as you would with a Cell:

```
List<Cell> rowCells = new ArrayList<Cell>();
rowCells.add(new MultilineCell(font, c.getString(reasonIdx), 42));
```

I know that extension is not a nice solution, and copying drawBorders() is even worse, but in this case, it is the only solution if you don't want to fork PDFJet.

This however breaks `autoAdjustColumnWidths`: the width is calculated on the whole text, instead of the longest line. So if you intend to use this method, either subclass `Table`, fork PDFJet, or extract just this method (the only downside of the latter is that I couldn't work around the cell padding though):

```
/**
 * Auto adjusts the widths of all columns so that they are just wide enough to hold the text without truncation.
 */
private static void autoAdjustColumnWidths(List<List<Cell>> tableData) {
    // Find the maximum text width for each column
    float[] max_col_widths = new float[tableData.get(0).size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < tableData.size(); i++) {
        List<Cell> row = tableData.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < row.size(); j++) {
            Cell cell = row.get(j);
            if (cell.getColSpan() == 1) {
                float cellWidth = 0f;
                if (cell.getImage() != null) {
                    cellWidth = cell.getImage().getWidth();
                }
                if (cell.getText() != null) {
                    // Is this a multiline cell? If so, measure the widest line
                    if (cell.getText().contains(MultilineCell.NEW_LINE)) {
                        String[] lines = cell.getText().split(MultilineCell.NEW_LINE);
                        for (String line : lines) {
                            if (cell.getFont().stringWidth(cell.getFallbackFont(), line) > cellWidth) {
                                cellWidth = cell.getFont().stringWidth(cell.getFallbackFont(), line);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // Standard (single-line) cell, measure whole text
                    else {
                        if (cell.getFont().stringWidth(cell.getFallbackFont(), cell.getText()) > cellWidth) {
                            cellWidth = cell.getFont().stringWidth(cell.getFallbackFont(), cell.getText());
                        }
                    }
                }
                cell.setWidth(cellWidth + 2f /*cell.left_padding*/ + 2f/*cell.right_padding*/);
                if (max_col_widths[j] == 0f ||
                        cell.getWidth() > max_col_widths[j]) {
                    max_col_widths[j] = cell.getWidth();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < tableData.size(); i++) {
        List<Cell> row = tableData.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < row.size(); j++) {
            Cell cell = row.get(j);
            cell.setWidth(max_col_widths[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

PDFJet is a funny library, btw: protected fields, every other method throws Exception, and the classes are definitely not designed for extension, even if there're not final.

Comment: Thx for that.
Copied WordUtils.wrap() from apache, Replaced the call to System.LINE_SEPARATOR and made some field in Cell protected...

Comment: Thanks for idea! Just change some in text x coordinate: `for (String line : lines) {
   float x_text = 0;
   switch (align) {
   case Align.LEFT:
    x_text = x + this.left_padding;
    break;
   case Align.CENTER:
    x_text = x + (this.width / 2 - this.font.stringWidth(line) / 2);
    break;
   case Align.RIGHT:
    x_text = x + (this.width - this.font.stringWidth(line))
      - this.right_padding;
   }
   page.drawString(this.font, line, x_text, y_text);
   y_text += this.font.getBodyHeight();
  }`

Comment: @HiXoid: you should probably submit an edit to the answer, the code in your comment is simply not readable :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a tricky solution for that:
As suggested before split your input into several lines (using for example using WordUtils from apache commons lang3)

```
String wrappedText = WrapUtil.wrap(super.getText(), this.characterCount);
 String[] lines = wrappedText.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

After you have your `lines`, add as many rows as lines into your table with those separate lines.
To simulate "multiline cell" call function `removeLineBetweenRows` providing index of those added rows. It will look like a one big cell.